# Zusatz in einer Adresse

Tags: meaning, word-choice

Mein Kunde hat seine Adresse so mitgeteilt:

> Berliner Str. XXX Zusatz Wendestieg X
>   38226 Salzgitter

Ich habe die Adresse gegoogelt, ohne Erfolg.
*Zusatz* ist ein *additive* (wahrscheinlich ein Kommentar zu einer existierenden Adresse).
Ich denke, dass wegen des Zusatzteils die Sendung verloren gehen kann. Oder ist das Standard?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Laut [dieser Seite](http://onlinestreet.de/strassen/Wendestieg.Salzgitter.232041.html) und [dieser Seite](https://www.google.de/maps/place/Berliner+Str.,+38226+Salzgitter/@52.1596442,10.3356772,76m/data=!3m1!1e3!4m2!3m1!1s0x47a550cbea3b59a3:0x97bb630e4179ae18?hl=de) treffen sich Berliner Straße und Wendestieg (die Durchfahrt scheint aber nicht möglich zu sein). Es gibt Häuser, die auf der Ecke liegen und deren Eingang oder Zufahrt nur über die Eckstraße erreichbar ist, obwohl sie postalisch zu der in diesem Fall größeren Hauptstraße gehören.

Solche Zusatzinformationen werden in Orten wie Berlin relativ häufig verwendet (z.B. "Hinterhof, Aufgang A 1") und sollten im Regelfall eher dazu dienen, dass die Sendung ankommt als dass sie verloren geht.

In Formularen zur Eingabe einer Adresse ist dies üblicherweise als optionaler Adresszusatz oder einfach als 2. Eingabezeile zur Straße vorgesehen. Siehe z.B. [hier](https://portal.epost.de/registration)

Comment: Oh, cool! Das ist das Reseach Effort, glaube ich! :-)

Comment: Sie treffen sich nicht; laut [OpenStreetMap](http://www.openstreetmap.org/), woher übrigens auch die verlinkte Karte stammt, gibt es keinen direkten Durchweg, selbst zu Fuß nur ein Stück weiter. Ich könnte mir vorstellen, daß es statt _Zusatz_ vielmehr _Zugang_ heißen sollte; es kommt vor, daß Häuser technisch zu einer Straße gehören, von der aus sie gar nicht (mehr) erreichbar sind.

Comment: @chirlu: Auch wenn "Zugang" hier inhaltlich ebenso Sinn ergeben würde, so ist der "Adresszusatz" durchaus ein fester Begriff im Postwesen (siehe z.B. das entsprechende Formularfeld [in diesem Formular](https://portal.epost.de/rip/registration-with-promotion/EPB35P3)).

Comment: @O. R. Mapper: Man schreibt das aber nicht in die Adresse. So wie auch _Nachname_ ein fester Begriff ist, man auf einen Brief aber nicht _Michaela Nachname Meier_ schreiben würde.

Comment: @chirlu: *Normalerweise* nicht, dennoch würde ich nicht ausschließen, dass gerade "seltenere" Felder wie der Adresszusatz mitunter auch mal explizit angegeben werden.

Answer (score 2):

Das ist unüblich, ich habe den Ausdruck »Zusatz« noch nie in einer Adresse gesehen.

Ich habe in Google maps nachgesehen, und herausgefunden, dass *Berliner Straße* und *Wendesteig* beide in Salzgitter liegen, aber 5 bis 6 km voneinander entfernt sind. Daher glaube ich, dass es sich um zwei verschiedene Adressen handelt.
Eine ist

> Berliner Str. XXX
>   38226 Salzgitter

die andere ist

> Wendestieg X
>   38226 Salzgitter

Ich vermute, dass es hier um zwei Adressen desselben Unternehmens handelt (einmal das Büro oder Geschäft, das andere könnte das Lager sein.)

Übrigens:
Bist du sicher, dass dort wirklich »*Zusatz*« steht? Oder steht dort »*zusätzl.*«? Denn das ist eine Abkürzung von »zusätzlich« (auf englisch »additionally«), und damit wäre für mich ganz klar, dass wirklich eine Hauptadresse und zusätzlich eine zweite Adresse gemeint sind.

Comment: Hallo Hubert, vielen Dank für die Antwort. Ja, bin ich sicher, dass in der Adresse das Wort "Zusatz" steht. Aber wegen des Names des Empfängers stelle ich fest, dass er auch Fremdsprächer ist. So konnte er die "Zusatz" und "zusätzl." einfach verwirren.

Comment: Bei Suche nach dem Buchstabendreher _Wendesteig_ liefert Google die _Wendegasse_ statt dem _Wendestieg_, vielleicht war das das Problem?

Comment: "Adresszusatz" ist ein von der deutschen Post für beliebige Zusatzinformationen verwendeter Begriff, beispielsweise in [diesem Formular](https://portal.epost.de/rip/registration-with-promotion/EPB35P3). Versendet man beispielsweise an einen registrierten Postkunden (z.B. an eine Packstation), [soll man die Kundennummer in das Feld "Adresszusatz" eintragen](http://www.dhl.de/content/dam/dhlde/downloads/pdf/geschaeftskunden/efulfillment/dhl-paket-basisinfo-versandhaendler-cand-go-111.pdf).

Comment: @O.R.Mapper: Das stimmt schon, aber eine 6 km weit entfernte Alternativ-Adresse ist nicht das, was die Post unter einem Zusatz versteht.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast: Das ist durchaus richtig, und an der Stelle kann ich mir auch wirklich nur vorstellen, dass es eigentlich hätte "z. Hd." hätte heißen sollen, als Weiterleitungsvermerk an die interne Hauspost der Empfängerorganisation. Was sollte ansonsten die zweite Adresse aussagen? "Falls das Gebäude an der Hauptadresse zufällig nicht mehr existiert - Abbruch o.ä. - bitte an die zweite Adresse zustellen."?